# How do I tell if one of my domains in Google Apps for Domains is an alias or a separate domain?

Tags: google-workspace

Some time ago I added a domain name to my Google Apps for Domains account.  I forgot whether or not I added it as an alias or as an independent domain name.  I cannot see in my list of domains anything to designate it as one or the other (see screenshot):

[image: Screenshot]

How do I know how this domain is configured?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google differentiates the two type of domain for you. If the domain is a separate domain, the status would just read "Active". However, if the domain is an alias of the primary domain, the status will read "Domain alias for *example.com*". So in the screenshot you provided, the domain you are pointing to is a separate domain.